# If I stop moving my (USB)mouse, it stops working until I click

Tags: 12.10, mouse

I have a usb Microsoft mouse that works fine on Windows, but on Ubuntu it stops working if I stop using it for three seconds (literally, I counted). At this point, I am unable to move it, I have to click, almost as if it wake the mouse up. And that sucks because apparently that click is a legit click and I end up closing out of stuff sometimes...

Anyway, please help if you've ran into this sort of problem before. I know that there's a chance that this is just an unsolvable hardware issue that I might just have to live with (or write a driver).

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Never had it with previous Ubuntus or previous computers (same microsoft usb mouse). Did you find a solution at the end ?

Comment: maybe some default values of variables changed in the kernel

Comment: What solved this problem in my case was executing this: `for i in /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/control; do echo on > $i; done`. You can find more information here: http://superuser.com/questions/408683/why-my-usb-mouse-gets-suspended-after-3-seconds-of-inactivity

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I encountered this same problem (although in a different way).

In my case it was due to agressive powersaving on USB ports.
This was something I did (to) myself.

If you want to change this behaviour (which, I guess, you do), you could create a permanent settings file to force USB always on.
Open a root console and type (or copy/paste):

```
echo 'ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", TEST=="power/control" ATTR{power/control}="on"' >/etc/udev/rules.d/usb_power_save.rules
```

Comment: I installed the package `laptop-mode-tools`. I am wondering if that might be what causes the aggressive powersaving. It only happens when I am running on battery.

Comment: What will be the impact on battery life?

Answer (score 3):

For those of you using powertop: `<TAB>` to "Tunables" section and make sure "Autosuspend for USB device" or "Autosuspend for unknown USB device" is off ("Bad" on left).

I was using `sudo powertop --auto-tune` in `/etc/rc.local`, so I had to add this afterwards: `for i in /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/control; do echo on > $i; done`.